# Deserialize/Decode CSLA.Net Requests and Responses

Tags: csla

What is the quickest way to deserialize and present in a readable format the communication between an application and a server using CSLA.Net?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WCF, you should be able to add a custom endpoint behaviour to your app.config file on your client.

Create a custom message inspector (example here just logs to the output window or trace):

```
public class OutputMessageInspector : IClientMessageInspector
{
    public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Request XML: ");
        Debug.WriteLine(request.ToString() ?? "<NULL>");
        return null;
    }

    public void AfterReceiveReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Response XML: ");
        Debug.WriteLine(reply.ToString() ?? "<NULL>");
    }
}
```

And add that message inspector to a custom Endpoint Behaviour:

```
public class CustomMessageInspectorBehavior : IEndpointBehavior
{
    public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
    {
        clientRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(new OutputMessageInspector());
    }

    public void Validate(ServiceEndpoint endpoint) { }

    public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters) { }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher) { }
}
```

Now just update your app.config WCF configurations to add the `CustomMessageInspectorBehavior` as an endpoint behaviour. [See MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702788%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)